# Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback how to fix this error

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, async-await

This code is not working it gives the error "Model.findOne() no longer accepts a callback".Fix the error without downgrade my mongoose version.

`router.post('/login', async(req, res) => {

```
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
const userType = req.body.userType;

let userSchema;
let redirectUrl;

// Set the user schema and redirect URL based on the user type
if (userType === 'customer') {
    userSchema = Customers;
    redirectUrl = '/customer/home';
} else if (userType === 'hotel_owner') {
    userSchema = HotelOwners;
    redirectUrl = '/hotel_owner/home';
} else if (userType === 'advertiser') {
    userSchema = Advertisers;
    redirectUrl = '/advertiser/home';
} else if (userType === 'destination_manager') {
    userSchema = DestinationManagers;
    redirectUrl = '/destination_manager/home';
} else if (userType === 'admin') {
    userSchema = Admin;
    redirectUrl = '/admin/home';
}

// Find the user in the corresponding schema
await userSchema.find({ email: email, password: password })
    .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
            // If user not found, return error message
            res.status(401).send({
                message: "Invalid email or password"
            });
        } else {
            // Redirect user to their respective home page
            res.redirect(redirectUrl);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Handle errors
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "An error occurred"
        });
    });
```

});`

How to fix the error and work this code

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `await` already, just do it like this:

```js
try {
    const user = await userSchema.findOne({email, password})
    if (!user) {
        //If there is no user match, do...
    }
    // If there is a user, do something below...
} catch (error) {
    // Handle error here
}
```

Also, I believe you have to use a model instead of schema to call functions like `find()`

```
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)
const users = User.find() // Or similar functions
```